# What is this plant, and should the lowermost leaves be curling up?

Tags: species-identification, botany

We've got a couple of these plants but have no idea how to look after them. Watering them regularly (every 2-3 days, or when the soil seems dry) seems to help. The pot rims are about a foot at their widest part.

However, we're concerned about the lower leaves drying up. Is this a normal part of this plants growth process and does it continue this way and produce a 'trunk' of sorts?

As a follow on question, do we need to re-pot these plants?

[image]

Comment: I think you are likely to find more knowledgeable help at [Gardening.stackexchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I believe these are two Foxtail Agaves (Agave attenuata). These resources may help you take care of them.

[Foxtail Agave Care Information](https://plantcaretoday.com/agave-attenuata.html)

And for the wilted leaves:
[How to Save a Dying Agave Plant](https://www.hunker.com/12619877/how-to-save-a-dying-agave-plant)

Also, the Gardening SE may be able to help more.

Hopefully this helps!

[image: Foxtail Agave]